# Datatable contenteditable problem cause scrollX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I have a problem with contenteditable.

when I use contenteditable on columns and when scrollX option is enabled, the columns are mis-aligned. Look at my screenshot [misaligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mtmr.png)

I tried many solutions on stackoverflow, but I was not successful.

However, this is my dataTable settings:

```
table = $('#sparepart_id').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "lengthChange": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": false,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "pageLength": 12,
    scrollX: true,
    "initComplete": function (settings, json) {  
        $("#sparepart_id").wrap("<div style='overflow:auto; width:100%;position:relative;'></div>");            
      },
   stateLoadCallback: function (settings) {
     var o;
     $.ajax( {
        url     : BASE_URL+"spareparts/load_layout",
        type    : "POST",
        data    : { module_table : "sparepart-list"},
        async   : false,
        dataType: 'json',
         success: function (json) {
             o = JSON.parse(json.json);
         },
         error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
         }
     } );
     return o;
 }
```

and in my HTML code i put

```
<td contenteditable="true"></td>
```

Comment: I think the problem is the value of lengthChange and autoWidth is false. you must also disable pageLength.

Comment: [ SOLVED ] Thanks guys i am use it `  word-break: break-all !important;cursor: text;white-space: pre-wrap !important;
`

Comment: Cool!, Answer you own question and you will get badge

Comment: LoL i don't need badge , i need knowledge

Comment: I know. if the other have same problem like you, you can help each other.

Comment: Please could add your fix as an answer, not as a comment? .Don`t change the title to solved. This can help someone to fix similar kind of a problem

Comment: @Jeremy, Instead posting the answer in your Question, Post it as Answer and accept it yourself, so that other users may get help from that.

Answer (score 0):

Do not have to mark this as Solution, or vote up.
This answer was found by the author of this question. I am listing this , to preserve question and answer pattern followed in SO

```
.class{
word-break: break-all !important;
cursor: text;
white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}
```